# How to optimize the low performance MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The below query finds one id by using the below query format but it seems I have indexed all columns, but it took time to execute between  54.3 seconds - 1.2 mins. What can I try next?

Query:

```
select 
  op.ord_prod_id 
FROM 
  ordered_product op, 
  payment_type pt, 
  account a, 
  service s, 
  payment_method pm, 
  acct_order ao, 
  acct_order_item aoi 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      op.type = 1 
      OR op.type = 2
    ) 
    AND (
      pt.description = 'Levis' 
      AND op.validity_end_date < '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' 
      AND op.validity_end_date >= '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' 
      AND op.acct_status_id = 1 
      AND op.is_Renewable = 'T' 
      AND a.bu_id = 103
    )
  ) 
  AND pm.type_id = pt.id 
  AND s.acct_id = a.acct_id 
  AND op.serv_id = s.serv_id 
  AND ao.pay_meth_id = pm.pay_method_id 
  AND aoi.order_id = ao.order_id 
  AND aoi.ord_prod_id = op.ord_prod_id 
ORDER BY 
  op.validity_end_date ASC
```

explain plan

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pt
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_pmttype_descrip,idx_description
          key: idx_pmttype_descrip
      key_len: 32
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,payment_method_type_id,Idx_type_id,idx_type_id_zip_code_last_digits
          key: payment_method_type_id
      key_len: 10
          ref: ccbuser.pt.id
         rows: 3297
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ao
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_pay_meth_id
          key: idx_pay_meth_id
      key_len: 11
          ref: ccbuser.pm.pay_method_id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: aoi
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_accttorderitem_orderid,idx_ord_prod_id
          key: idx_accttorderitem_orderid
      key_len: 10
          ref: ccbuser.ao.order_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: op
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_ord_prod_servid,idx_ord_prod_statprod,idx_ordprod_type,idx_ord_prod_ve_date,idx_ord_prod_acct_status_id,idx_combo,idx_is_renewable,idx_validity_package_ind_acct_status
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 10
          ref: ccbuser.aoi.ord_prod_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_service_acctid
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 10
          ref: ccbuser.op.serv_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_account_buidasid,idx_combo,idx_bu_id,idx_1
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 10
          ref: ccbuser.s.acct_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
7 rows in set, 11 warnings (0.03 sec)
```

i have given show warnings;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 4. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 5. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 6. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 7. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 8. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 9. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 10. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1292
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT' for column 'validity_end_date' at row 1
*************************** 11. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1003
Message: /* select#1 */ select 
  .`op`.`ord_prod_id` AS `ord_prod_id` 
from 
  `ordered_product` `op` 
  join `payment_type` `pt` 
  join `account` `a` 
  join `service` `s` 
  join `payment_method` `pm` 
  join `acct_order` `ao` 
  join `acct_order_item` `aoi` 
where 
  (
    (
      `op`.`ord_prod_id` = `aoi`.`ord_prod_id`
    ) 
    and (
      `aoi`.`order_id` = `ao`.`order_id`
    ) 
    and (
      `ao`.`pay_meth_id` = `pm`.`pay_method_id`
    ) 
    and (
      `s`.`serv_id` = `op`.`serv_id`
    ) 
    and (
      `a`.`acct_id` = `s`.`acct_id`
    ) 
    and (
      `pm`.`type_id` = `pt`.`id`
    ) 
    and (
      `op`.`is_Renewable` = 'T'
    ) 
    and (
      `pt`.`description` = 'Credit Card'
    ) 
    and (
      (`op`.`type` = 1) 
      or (`op`.`type` = 2)
    ) 
    and (
      `op`.`validity_end_date` < '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT'
    ) 
    and (
      `op`.`validity_end_date` >= '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT'
    ) 
    and (
      `op`.`acct_status_id` = 1
    ) 
    and (`a`.`bu_id` = 103)
  ) 
order by 
  `op`.`validity_end_date`
```

All the rows scan one row, some of them scan 3k for one row - do I have to use str_to_date functions for the above one, are there any ways to improve performance?

Table structure:

```
       Table: ordered_product
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `ordered_product` (
  `acct_status_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `anual_prepay_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `equip_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ord_prod_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `package_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `package_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `parent_ord_prod_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remove_flag` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `serv_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `srv_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `srv_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `split_prod_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `term` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_charged` decimal(20,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason_code_id` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_charged` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validity_period` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validity_duration` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validity_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_amount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applied_wallet_amount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applied_rate_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partner_domain` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_Renewable` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coupon_external_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `validity_extended_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancellation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec_indicator` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_duration` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commitment_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `contact_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscription_status_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bu_charged_currency_id` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_code` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `legacy_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_service_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_channel_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applied_prod_rate_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applied_prod_rate_in_charged_currency_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applied_prod_price` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_to_parent` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ord_prod_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_servid` (`serv_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_statprod` (`acct_status_id`,`prod_id`,`package_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_bs_date` (`bill_start_date`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_be_date` (`bill_end_date`),
  KEY `ordered_product_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_ordprod_type` (`type`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_ve_date` (`validity_end_date`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_prod_id` (`prod_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_srv_start_date` (`srv_start_date`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_pack_id` (`package_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_acct_status_id` (`acct_status_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_validity_extend_dt` (`validity_extended_date`),
  KEY `idx_remove_flag` (`remove_flag`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_srv_end_date` (`srv_end_date`),
  KEY `idx_subscription_status_id` (`subscription_status_id`),
  KEY `idx_coupon_code` (`coupon_code`),
  KEY `idx_parent_ord_prod_id` (`parent_ord_prod_id`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`type`,`serv_id`),
  KEY `idx_is_renewable` (`is_Renewable`),
  KEY `idx_package_ind` (`package_ind`),
  KEY `idx_validity_package_ind_acct_status` (`validity_end_date`,`package_ind`,`acct_status_id`),
  KEY `idx_legacyid` (`legacy_id`),
  KEY `idx_cancellation_date` (`cancellation_date`),
  KEY `idx_suspend_start_date` (`suspend_start_date`),
  KEY `idx_suspend_end_date_validity_end_date_combo` (`suspend_end_date`,`validity_end_date`,`acct_status_id`,`is_Renewable`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: payment_type
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `payment_type` (
  `auto_pay_capable_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `can_post_credit_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `check_number_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `display_order` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `requires_gateway_ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `image_url` varchar(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_group` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_pmttype_descrip` (`description`),
  KEY `idx_display_name` (`display_name`),
  KEY `idx_description` (`description`),
  KEY `idx_payment_group` (`payment_group`),
  KEY `idx_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: account
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `acct_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `acct_status_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `acct_type_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attach_bill_cycle` char(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `bb_acct_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_del_type_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_bill_mode` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `bu_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `acct_comment` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `compliment_acct` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `corporate_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direct_acct` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_not_auto_script` char(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_inv_format` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id_prefix` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id_suffix` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inter_pic_id` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `intra_pic_id` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `legacy_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partner_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `psa_acct_id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_reg_num` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_method` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_add_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_exempt` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_number` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `tv_dma_id` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_change_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_creation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_person` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `offer_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cancel_reasons_id` int(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_addl_info_id` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vpn_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified_channel` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_logins_count` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_role_id` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mso_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mso_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anonymized` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parental_control` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `act_state_id` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `complaintmode_acct` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `mobile_verified` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_sub_type_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`acct_id`),
  KEY `idx_account_customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `idx_account_buidasid` (`bu_id`,`acct_status_id`),
  KEY `idx_account_bbaccountid` (`bb_acct_id`),
  KEY `idx_create_date` (`create_date`),
  KEY `idx_contact_id` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `idx_attach_bill_cycle` (`attach_bill_cycle`),
  KEY `idx_act_state` (`act_state_id`),
  KEY `idx_accountt_legacyid` (`legacy_id`),
  KEY `account_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_account_acctroleid` (`acct_role_id`),
  KEY `idx_extrnl_suffix` (`external_id_suffix`),
  KEY `idx_extrnl_prefix` (`external_id_prefix`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`bu_id`,`psa_acct_id`),
  KEY `idx_bu_id` (`bu_id`),
  KEY `idx_acct_reg_num` (`acct_reg_num`),
  KEY `idx_acct_stat_id` (`acct_status_id`),
  KEY `account_idx_combo4` (`tax_number`,`acct_id`,`contact_id`,`bu_id`),
  KEY `idx_1` (`bu_id`,`customer_id`),
  KEY `idx_acct_type_id` (`acct_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



       Table: service
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `acct_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `acct_status_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_not_auto_script` char(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_billed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serv_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pending_suspension_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reactivation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `suspend_duration` decimal(20,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serv_id`),
  KEY `idx_service_acctid` (`acct_id`),
  KEY `idx_service_locid` (`loc_id`),
  KEY `service_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_service_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: payment_method
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `payment_method` (
  `account_number` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `bob_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_method_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `credit_card_type_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_meth_type_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `security_code` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `str_addr` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acct_type_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_phone` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `rtn` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drivers_license` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_out` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `storage_token` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payer_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_digits` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dc_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eci` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cavv` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ucaf_authentication_data` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ucaf_collection_ind` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscription_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effort_id` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receipt_data` longtext,
  `transaction_id` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_transaction_id` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_area_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `nick_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iin` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_unlimited` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_of_bank` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_finger_print` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_issuer_country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_service_provider` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pay_method_id`),
  KEY `payment_method_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_pmtmethod_transid` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `idx_payment_method_start_dt` (`start_date`),
  KEY `payment_method_start_date` (`start_date`),
  KEY `payment_method_bob_id` (`bob_id`),
  KEY `payment_method_type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `idx_pm_accountno` (`account_number`),
  KEY `idx_exp_date` (`expiration_date`),
  KEY `idx_org_transaction_id` (`org_transaction_id`),
  KEY `idx_transaction_id` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `Idx_bob_id` (`bob_id`),
  KEY `idx_account_number` (`account_number`),
  KEY `Idx_type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `i_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_last_digits` (`last_digits`),
  KEY `idx_ref_number` (`ref_number`),
  KEY `ix_refer_num` (`ref_number`),
  KEY `idx_zipcode` (`zip_code`),
  KEY `idx_card_fingerprint` (`card_finger_print`),
  KEY `idx_phone_number` (`phone_number`),
  KEY `idx_type_id_zip_code_last_digits` (`type_id`,`zip_code`,`last_digits`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: acct_order
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `acct_order` (
  `acct_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `ao_wf_instance_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comm` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_id` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_status` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `house_hold_user` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `legacy_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modify_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `order_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `promise_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `remove_flag` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `serv_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `txn_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workflow_instance_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_order_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_number` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pmt_profile_id` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_meth_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `txn_summary_id` int(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recon_required` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `idx_acctorder_acctid` (`acct_id`),
  KEY `idx_acctorder_wfiid` (`workflow_instance_id`),
  KEY `idx_acctorder_servid` (`serv_id`),
  KEY `idx_ao_mod_dt` (`modify_date`),
  KEY `idx_ext_id` (`external_order_id`),
  KEY `acct_order_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_pmt_profile_id` (`pmt_profile_id`),
  KEY `idx_ref_number` (`ref_number`),
  KEY `idx_pay_meth_id` (`pay_meth_id`),
  KEY `idx_txn_id` (`txn_id`),
  KEY `idx_promise_date` (`promise_date`),
  KEY `idx_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_ao_wf_instance_id` (`ao_wf_instance_id`),
  KEY `idx_acct_id_legacy_id` (`acct_id`,`legacy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: acct_order_item
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `acct_order_item` (
  `modify_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ord_prod_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `order_item_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `modified_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_item_id`),
  KEY `idx_accttorderitem_orderid` (`order_id`),
  KEY `idx_ord_prod_id` (`ord_prod_id`),
  KEY `acct_order_item_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_acct_order_item_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`),
  KEY `idx_modified_ts` (`modified_ts`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Have you tried using valid datetimes and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @P.Salmon can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: It's not an answer mysql should be equally performant with comma and implicit joins , implicit though is much more readable..

Comment: I was thinking the same ok let me check with that hash join.

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: Stop using `,` to join tables. The ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax is 30 years old, that's plenty of time to have adopted its use.

Comment: Please change `    (
      op.type = 1 
      OR op.type = 2
    ) 
` to `op.type IN (1,2)`, then get rid of all the parens in the `WHERE`.  (Won't change speed, but will make it easier to parse.

Comment: Those are mightly large numbers -- and they take a bunch of space.  Consider shrinking the definitions.  For example `DECIMAL(22,0)` takes 10 bytes and handles numbers up to 9999999999999999999999.  And `quantity` is ridiculously large, more quantity of atoms in a human being!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-arranging your query, you get this...

```
SELECT
  op.ord_prod_id 
FROM 
  account             AS a
INNER JOIN
  service             AS s
    ON s.acct_id = a.acct_id
INNER JOIN
  ordered_product     AS op
    ON op.serv_id = s.serv_id
INNER JOIN
  acct_order_item     AS aoi
    ON aoi.ord_prod_id = op.ord_prod_id
INNER JOIN
  acct_order          AS ao
    ON aoi.order_id = ao.order_id
INNER JOIN
  payment_method      AS pm
    ON ao.pay_meth_id = pm.pay_method_id
INNER JOIN
  payment_type        AS pt
    ON pm.type_id = pt.id
WHERE 
      a.bu_id = 103
  AND op.type IN (1,2)
  AND op.validity_end_date < '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' 
  AND op.validity_end_date >= '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT'
  AND op.acct_status_id = 1 
  AND op.is_Renewable = 'T' 
  AND pt.description = 'Levis' 
ORDER BY 
  op.validity_end_date ASC
```

This looks wrong to me, but I can't tell without the database schema.

Here's why I think it's wrong...

- Get all accounts with `bu_id = 103`
- Get all of those accounts' services (the same service may appear multiple times)
- Get all ordered products associated to those services ***regardless of account***

I strongly suspect that `acct_order` has an `acct_id` column, which would likely enable something like this...

```
SELECT
  op.ord_prod_id 
FROM 
  account             AS a
INNER JOIN
  acct_order          AS ao
    ON ao.acct_id = a.acct_id

INNER JOIN
  payment_method      AS pm
    ON pm.pay_method_id = ao.pay_meth_id
INNER JOIN
  payment_type        AS pt
    ON pt.id = pm.type_id

INNER JOIN
  acct_order_item     AS aoi
    ON aoi.order_id = ao.order_id
INNER JOIN
  ordered_product     AS op
    ON op.ord_prod_id = aoi.ord_prod_id
--
-- No need to join on service now
--
WHERE 
      a.bu_id = 103
  AND pt.description = 'Levis' 
  AND op.type IN (1,2)
  AND op.acct_status_id = 1 
  AND op.is_Renewable = 'T' 
  AND op.validity_end_date >= '2022-09-18 00:00:00 Etc/GMT'
  AND op.validity_end_date <  '2022-09-18 11:24:08 Etc/GMT' 
ORDER BY 
  op.validity_end_date ASC
```

That alone will likely reduce the number of rows being processed, and give insights into what indexes you want, potentially being...

```
account (bu_id, acct_id)
acct_order (acct_id, pay_meth_id, order_id)

payment_method (pay_method_id, type_id) or (type_id, pay_method_id)
payment_type (id, description) or (description, id)

acct_order_item (order_id, ord_prod_id)
ordered_product (type, acct_status_id, is_renewable, validity_end_date, ord_prod_id)
```

You should also fix the date literal being used in the `WHERE` clause.

Either way, if you want a more categorical response, you need to include the full schema for those tables, including indexes and foreign keys (to validate your joins) as well as row counts, cardinality, etc (to direct you on index creation, performance tuning, etc).

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to remove `description` per Rick James's comment.**

An index designed match your query will make it faster. (But it won't make it correct if it's wrong, just sayin'.)

You filter your `ordered_product` table on:

- type (two values)
- account_status_id (equality)
- is_Renewable (equality)
- validity_end_date (date range)

So try an index with all the equality match columns followed by the range column. MySql can random-access it to the first eligible column and then scan it sequentially. Fast.

```sql
CREATE INDEX desc_stat_renew_date ON ordered_product
     (acct_status_id, is_Renewable, validity_end_date);
```

To learn about this, see Marcus Winad's excellent https://use-the-index-luke.com/  .

**Pro tip** Using mixed case in column or table names can cause confusion if/when you migrate to another server machine. Avoid!

Comment: hi @Jones i have mentioned the table structure.

Comment: Cool. Add an index like the one I suggested. The EXPLAIN row for that table says it scanned the entire PK. Also, review your choices for your other indexes. Multicolumn indexes starting with date/time columns are definitely a code smell, because indexes for filtering on ranges should have the range column last.

Comment: Of course, thanks for the info, can you suggest which query is best after indexing?

Comment: like suggested query or old query @O. Jones

Comment: `description` is not in `op`, so the index won't work.  (So why is it the "approved" answer??)

Comment: Darn.  You're right. I misread the alias in the query. It's `pt.description` not `op.description`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are several orders in which the Optimizer might evaluate the query.  Here are some additional indexes that the optimizer might use, especially if it chooses to start with `op`.

```
op: INDEX(acct_status_id, is_Renewable, type, validity_end_date, serv_id, ord_prod_id)
op: INDEX(acct_status_id, is_Renewable, validity_end_date, type, serv_id, ord_prod_id)
```

Comment: got it  let me check with that and thanks for the info @Rick James